# Access token validation failure - MS Graph API Version 2

Tags: outlook, azure-active-directory, office365, microsoft-graph-api

I had googled a lot on this issue yet nothing helped me. I had seen many similar post also but no useful.

I am using MS Graph API V2 to access user emails,calendar and contacts data.

*Authorize URL:*

https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=ABC&redirect_uri=redirectURL&response_type=code&scope=Mail.Read(ScopeURL)

*Token Request URL:*

https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token

```
Headers:

Content-Type:application/x-www-url-form-urlencoded

Body: 

client_id:ABC
redirect_uri:RedirectURL
grant_type:authorization_code
client_secret:KEY
code: pasted from browser URL
```

I am successfully getting **code** in browser URL after signing in and using same **code** to get access token also.

*User Profile/Mail Messages/Contacts Request:*

Ex: I am trying to read user profile as well user mail messages.

Respective Requests:

```
Profile: https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/

Mail Messages: https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages

Header: Authorization:Bearer (AccessToken pasted from token request)
```

But I am getting below error whichever request in above using.

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "InvalidAuthenticationToken",
        "message": "Access token validation failure.",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "1e232525-6772-483e-87e3-679d5fcb8fb5",
            "date": "2019-02-22T11:53:50"
        }
    }
}
```

I had set permissions for mail read and write , access calendars data, contacts ( Full access)

I created application in https://apps.dev.microsoft.com

Comment: Have you tried to validate token using http://jwt.ms?

Comment: Yes, I had validated token and its a valid.

Comment: You would make your life easier by using the MSAL library to do the OAuth flow for you.  There are plenty of steps where you can go wrong. If you really don't want to do that, one thing I would suggest trying is to prefix your scopes with https://graph.microsoft.com/

Comment: Yes i used scope as like you mentioned, its worked for me. Thanks. But i created app in "https://apps.dev.microsoft.com" and created scopes manually and used specific scope url. Ex: api://<APPID>/Mail.Read. Is this causing issue for me? will it wont work? what is wrong in this?

Comment: How ever, I am not able to get "me/contacts" data from API even though i set permissions.What could be reason. Error: Resource not found

Answer (score 1):

The scope format should be `https://graph.microsoft.com/Mail.Read Mail.ReadWrite User.Read`. I tried the following, it worked.

[image]

To get me/contacts, you need to grant the `Contacts.Read` and `Contacts.ReadWrtie` permissions.

[image]

And when you required the access_token, the authorization URL should like this:
`https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?`(need to use the `common` to replace the `tenant name`).

[image]

Comment: Yes i used scope as like you mentioned, its worked for me. Thanks. But i created app in "https://apps.dev.microsoft.com" and created scopes manually and used specific scope url. Ex: api://<APPID>/Mail.Read. Is this causing issue for me? will it wont work? what is wrong in this?

Comment: Yes. Expose API means you set up your app as an api, the url is your app not the ms graph api.

Comment: If it is useful for you, please help make a mark for this, thanks.

Comment: I am not able to get "me/contacts" data from API even though i set permissions.What could be reason. Error: Resource not found

Comment: @PavanKumarGVVS. I already update my answer, please have a look. thanks.